# Swift 4 Firebase .childAdded not retrieving latest record

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am trying to retrieve the latest child added to my child, for example:

```
3D373545-2C7C-470F-9A79-C98C3BF90E0A
   -Ll-gQ3TB9W9pH8Z3Gn6
    message: test
    username: test
   -Ll-gSbe4C0iS7R3V0Dy
    message: test
    username: test
```

The problem I encounter is when I first insert a record (key ending in Gn6), it cannot retrieve that. However when I insert the second record (key ending in 0Dy), it retrieves the previous record (ending in Gn6). This goes on and on.

```
  FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference().child("messages/" + key).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot, key) in

        print("New record key is  : ")

        print(key)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attach an observer for `.childAdded` that your completion handler will be triggered for each child that matches the observer. And since you don't limit the observer in any way, your callback will be triggered for each node under `"messages/" + key`.

If you only want to get the last node, you'll need to observe a query that only listens for that last node. Since you seem to be using `childByAutoId()`, the child nodes are already chronologically ordered and you can do:

```
FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference().child("messages/" + key)
  .queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 1)
  .observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot, key) in
    ...
```